# why does userDefaults not working in this code

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   
    var nameInputTextField = UITextField()
    var nameLabel = UILabel()
    var button = UIButton()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
       let storedName =  UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "name")
        
        if let userName = storedName as? String {
            nameLabel.text = userName
        }
        
        let width = view.frame.size.width
        let height = view.frame.size.height
        
        nameInputTextField.placeholder = "Name"
        nameInputTextField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        nameInputTextField.textAlignment = .center
        nameInputTextField.frame = CGRect(x: width * 0.5 - width * 0.8/2 , y: height * 0.2 - height * 0.04/2, width: width * 0.8, height: height * 0.04)
        view.addSubview(nameInputTextField)
        
        nameLabel.text = "Your name: "
        nameLabel.textAlignment = .center        nameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: Int(width * 0.5 - width * 0.8/2) , y: Int(height * 0.3 - height * 0.04/2), width: Int(width * 0.8), height: Int(height * 0.04))
        view.addSubview(nameLabel)
        
        button.setTitle("Click to save", for: UIControl.State.normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: width * 0.5 - width * 0.3/2, y: height * 0.4 - height * 0.06/2, width: width * 0.3, height: height * 0.06)
        view.addSubview(button)
        
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.whenClicked), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
              
          }
          
    @objc func whenClicked(_ sender: Any) {
            nameLabel.text = "Your name: \(nameInputTextField.text!)"
              UserDefaults.standard.set(nameInputTextField.text!, forKey: "name")

          }

        
    }
```

Hello, I have been learning Swift, and I learned how to store data on the phone with userDefaults. I tried it with adding labels and textfields by drag and drop, but this time I decided to create those by writing myself, but this time code is not working (It's not saving the data). What is wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to the question but there is `string(forKey:)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you set the text value of your **nameLabel** two times. Delete the

```
nameLabel.text = "Your name: "
```

line and consider the following suggestion:

```
if let userName = storedName as? String {
        nameLabel.text = "Your name: \(userName)"
} else {
        nameLabel.text = "Your name: "
}
```

Comment: Or `let userNAme = (storedName as? String) ?? ""` and then `nameLabel.text = "Your name: '\(userName)\'"`.

Comment: (The above is a nit. This looks like a correct answer to the question. (Voted)